# How to write Spin weighted spherical Harmonics in Mathematica?

Tags: special-functions

I want to do some calculations which involve spin-weighted spherical harmonics of spin weight -2. How can I write that in Mathematica? Is there any built-in symbol for that?

Comment: Have you seen: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SpinWeightedSphericalHarmonics/

Comment: Yes. I have seen it. But it doesn't show how to write it in Mathematica. I do not want to plot anything. I want to do analytical calculations, integrations that involve spin-weighted spherical harmonics of spin weight -2.

Comment: @apk Then please include what you've tried so far and what calculations you would like to carry out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the source of the [demonstrations project](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SpinWeightedSphericalHarmonics/) Daniel mentioned his comment, which contains the definition you are looking for

```
Y[s_, l_, m_, th_, ph_] := (-1)^m*Simplify[
  Sqrt[((l + m)!*(l - m)!*(2*l + 1))/((l + s)!*(l - s)!*4*Pi)]*
   Sin[th/2]^(2*l)*Sum[
     Binomial[l - s, r]*Binomial[l + s, r + s - m]*
     (-1)^(l - r - s)*E^(I*m*ph)*Cot[th/2]^(2*r + s - m), 
  {r, 0, l - s}], 
  Assumptions -> {Element[ph, Reals], Element[th, Reals]}
];
```

This is a direct implementation of the formula found on Wikipedia (which itself is taken from eq. (3.1) of [this](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1705135#) paper, with a different normalization).

Comment: Thanks. And for its conjugate, i.e. for Y bar (l,m,s), I will just replace I with -I in the above formula i.e the only change will be the term E^(-I m phi) in the above formula instead of  E^(I m phi). Right?

Comment: I'm not sure if the relation Y bar (l,m,s) = Y(-l,m,s) holds, but you are better up applying a `UpSet` such as `Conjugate@Y[s_, l_, m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] ^= 
 Y[s, l, m, \[Theta], -\[Phi]]`.

You can also use the SpinWeightedSpherodialHarmonics package from https://bhptoolkit.org/users.html